# Inter-language 2-cycle quine

Tags: code-challenge, quine

## Challenge

Create 2 programs A and B

- The output of program A is exactly program B
- The output of program B is exactly program A
- Neither program should depend on inputs to yield the correct output
- A and B are not identical programs
- A and B are of different programming languages
- Neither program may be equivalent to itself in the other language.
  For example, if the chosen languages are C and C++, the C++ program
  must not be a valid and equivalent C program, else the
  "inter-language" requirement is redundant

A solution should include:

- The program source, as well as a [Try it online (tio.run)](https://tio.run/#) link for both programs

## Scoring

The score for a solution is:

- The length of the shortest program +
- The combined length of the names of both programming languages, as they appear on tio.run

The reason for this unusual scoring is because this constitutes the combined length of the minimum information necessary to communicate your solution.

---

This is my first post to Code Golf.
Any edits to this post to increase clarity or appropriate vocabulary are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I would really recommend removing the name penalty.  "Common name" is not going to be clear for a lot of instances.  I don't really get the reason this was included in the first place and it just leads to trouble down the road when people try to golf the language name.

Comment: Also not an issue or even something that needs to be changed, but the penultimate and antepenultimate bullets are redundant, both are implied by the last bullet point.

Comment: So essentially, this is a multi-language quine that can't be a polyglot.

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter I did suspect that the "Common name" qualifier may cause some problems, but for now I'd like to leave it as a (maybe naive) experiment in seeing how such an odd type of scoring will play out.

Comment: @Jono2906 no problem if either program can "speak" both languages, i.e. is a valid program in both languages, but if it gives the same output in both, that violates the last rule.  See Jo King's answer

Comment: @HymsForDisco but you say that A and B cannot be the same program. A polyglot is a program that does the same task in both languages.

Comment: @Jono2906 I see. I was unfamiliar with the common meaning of "polyglot" in programming.  I took it to mean any program that is simply *valid* in more than one language (not necessarily accomplishing the same task in each language).  Anyways, the original rules and wording still stand, any corrections will be made there.

Comment: If you want to leave it you really ought to clarify what you mean then.  A language can have multiple names, and some may be initialisms or nicknames. Can I say haskell is GHC even if it works in other haskell compilers? Can I say Prolog is SWI if it works in the SWI-Prolog interpreter?  If my python answer works in both Python 2 and Python 3 can I just say Python (does it need to work in Python 1 as well)? If I have C code that only works with a particular compiler is it still just C or do I have to use the longer compiler name?  There are a ton of edge cases that are not clear from the spec.

Comment: Hi! This seems similar to my posts, I love the creativity!

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) and [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 18 bytes + 3 + 6 = 27

```
'3d*:5-0@o~r{?H>o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X904RcvKVNfAIb@uqNrewy7f5v9/AA)

and

```
"3d*:5-0@o~r{?H>o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X8k4RcvKVNfAIb@uqNrewy7f5v9/AA)

Both output the same program, but with the first character flipped between `'` and `"`. Neither program is equivalent to itself in the other language, since the behaviour of `@` differs.

Comment: So the first is a Gol><> quine and the second is a ><> quine that both just happen to produce the same output in the other language? Seems that makes them equivalent to me, but what do I know?

Comment: Indeed this solution is quite a "near-miss", but both programs have different outputs in each language as outputted by "try it online".  I'm interested to see how the problem becomes (presumably) more complicated with non-golfing and more dissimilar languages

Comment: Sure, by running the first program in ><> and the second program in Gol><> they output each other, but that's not what I said.

Comment: Yes this is a valid. By "near-miss" I meant that it narrowly dodges each restriction i.e. 1. the programs are not identical, 2. the languages are not the same, and 3. neither program is equivalent in the other language

Comment: Ah I see now, both programs are equivalent to each other in the same language.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes + 8 = score 21

```
“Ṿ;⁾v`+/ŒṘ”v`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4oCc4bm@O@KBvnZgKy/FkuG5mOKAnXZg//8)

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad)

```
'“Ṿ;⁾v`+/ŒṘ”v`'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9yYWT//yfigJzhub474oG@dmArL8WS4bmY4oCddmAn//8)

A Jelly quine that wraps itself in single quotes, such that the resultant RAD program simply prints the original Jelly program back out.

Thanks to @JoKing for golfing the language name for the second program!